# CDK drag-n-drop auto scroll

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular7, autoscroll, angular-cdk

I have an Angular 7 app, using CDK Drag-n-Drop to drag and drop rows in a very long list.

What should I do to allow the long list to auto scroll when the dragged item out of the current view?

Any sample code I can refer to?

Comment: Did you find your answer ? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @AdrienPESSU Sorry, no good solution so far. Please share if you got a good one

Comment: Didn't solve it yet. My only lead on this is to re arrange my scrollable div.

Comment: Not a solution for Angular 7, but with a version upgrade you'll find this feature has recently been implemented: https://github.com/angular/components/pull/16382

Comment: I am also looking for solution to this

Comment: Any solution for this? @user2777473

Comment: I've posted an answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755127/angular-cdk-issue-with-scrolling-and-dragging-element-inside-nested-scrollable/64686415#64686415

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16677#issuecomment-762840674) you just need to add `cdkScrollable` to your list container.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue, It happens anytime an outside element is scrollable. This is the open issue - https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16677. - I have slightly modified the solution mentioned in this link.

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDrag } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Directive({
  selector: '[cdkDrag],[actualContainer]',
})
export class CdkDropListActualContainerDirective {
  @Input('actualContainer') actualContainer: string;
  originalElement: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  constructor(cdkDrag: CdkDrag) {
    cdkDrag._dragRef.beforeStarted.subscribe( () => {
      var cdkDropList = cdkDrag.dropContainer;
      if (!this.originalElement) {
        this.originalElement = cdkDropList.element;
      }

      if ( this.actualContainer ) {
        const element = this.originalElement.nativeElement.closest(this.actualContainer) as HTMLElement;
        cdkDropList._dropListRef.element = element;
        cdkDropList.element = new ElementRef<HTMLElement>(element);
      } else {
        cdkDropList._dropListRef.element = cdkDropList.element.nativeElement;
        cdkDropList.element = this.originalElement;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Template

```
 <div mat-dialog-content class="column-list">
    <div class="column-selector__list">
      <div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div
          *ngFor="let column of data"
          cdkDrag
          actualContainer="div.column-list"
        >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```