# Angular CDK - issue with scrolling and dragging element inside nested scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-cdk

Prerequisite: cdk draggable elements inside a nested scrollable `div`
(see  the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7y19nm?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html))

How to reproduce:

1. Start dragging an item.
2. Scroll the page
3. Drag item a bit more when not scrolling

Effect: item placeholder stays in wrong place and it's basically impossible to drag item anywhere outside the viewport.

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto">
  <div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>{{movie}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the virtual scroll cdk for the scrollable div?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 10):

I've searched for this issue in the [Angular components' official Github repository](https://github.com/angular/components) and I have found the following topics:

- https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13588
- https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16535

There are different solutions depending on the version that you use: **Angular 9+** (works also with **Angular 10**) or **Angular 8**:

### Angular 9+ (works also Angular 10)

From version **9.1.0**, the scrolling of the parent element is supported by setting the `cdkScrollable` directive to it.

So, for v9.1.0 and up, the following code should work:

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto" cdkScrollable>
  <div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>{{movie}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Stackblitz demo**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swaqkk-yjiz7r
(*uses v10.0.1*)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vszdat (*uses v9.2.4*)

---

### Angular 8

From version **8.1.0**, the scrolling was enabled, but **only** for the **cdkDropList itself** or the **viewport** (for performance reasons). So there are two solutions available:

1. We can set the fixed height and the `overflow: scroll` to the `cdkDropList` element:

```html
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>{{movie}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Stackblitz demo**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avezy6

2. If we can't make the `cdkDropList` scrollable and there is a parent element that should scroll (*like the situation in the question*), I've adapted a solution found here (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16677#issuecomment-562625427):
   we can use a custom directive `cdkDropListScrollContainer`, that will be set on the `cdkDrag` elements. This directive will take as a `Input` the reference to the parent element that should scroll:

```html
<div class="example-container" style="height: 500px; overflow-y: auto" #scrollContainer>
  <div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div
      class="example-box"
      *ngFor="let movie of movies"
      cdkDrag
      [cdkDropListScrollContainer]="scrollContainer">
      {{movie}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code for the directive is:

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { CdkDrag } from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";

@Directive({
  selector: "[cdkDropListScrollContainer]"
})
export class CdkDropListScrollContainerDirective {
  @Input("cdkDropListScrollContainer") scrollContainer: HTMLElement;
  originalElement: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  constructor(cdkDrag: CdkDrag) {

    cdkDrag._dragRef.beforeStarted.subscribe(() => {
      const cdkDropList = cdkDrag.dropContainer;
      if (!this.originalElement) {
        this.originalElement = cdkDropList.element;
      }

      if (this.scrollContainer) {
        const element = this.scrollContainer;
        cdkDropList._dropListRef.element = element;
        cdkDropList.element = new ElementRef<HTMLElement>(element);
      } else {
        cdkDropList._dropListRef.element = cdkDropList.element.nativeElement;
        cdkDropList.element = this.originalElement;
      }
    });

  }
}
```

**Stackblitz demo**:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkuqhg

Comment: On using the directive method I am getting an error as "Cannot assign to 'element' because it is a read-only property." for line "cdkDropList._dropListRef.element = element" and "cdkDropList._dropListRef.element = cdkDropList.element.nativeElement"