# angular cdk drag drop - adjust autoscroll speed when dragging

Tags: angular, browser, autoscroll, angular-cdk, angular-dragdrop

UPDATE 11.07.2020

Issue on Github https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19401

ORIGINAL POST

Is there a way to adjust the scroll speed when dragging an item down or up the list?
In Firefox on macOS, it behaves as expected, scrolling faster the further down I drag the item.
In Chrome and Safari, there seems to be only one speed.

For me, the behavior in Chrome would be most important, since I plan to use drag-drop in an ionic project.

Does anybody know if the scroll is a custom javascript implementation in the CDK or some native browser feature?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-autoscroll?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71401566/1440240

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using "cdkDropListAutoScrollStep" property of CdkDropList. Requires angular material v11

Documentation here: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api

Comment: Thx this is what I was looking for! Cheers!